# Using SignalR, is it possible to do a bulk push of messages to a changing collection of clients?

Tags: push-notification, client-side, server-push, signalr

What I'm asking for may be different than a group push where the collection of clients normally remain relatively constant.

In a notification system, clients can create events that not all other clients are subscribed to.  For example, a client indicates that they don't want to receive notifications of new logins, but wants to know when a new photo is published from only certain users.  The combinations are endless, and created on the fly, so you can't do a group push.

On each event, a new collection of clients will be created that will receive a notification.  Is there a way to accomplish this with a bulk push rather than individual private messages?

Would the way to implement this be to create groups on the fly (on the server side), add clients to that group then send a message to that group?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why you need groups for this? Clients that subscribe to event foo via:

```
$.connection.myHub.foo = function() { }
```

Will be notified of the event. Where we aren't so good right now is with dynamically creating and removing events but that support will be improved.

If you want something dynamic, your only option would be to use groups.

Comment: Users can subscribe to events, yes, however some users may not want to see some events from other users or allow users to see their events.  For example, you have banned a user from viewing your "events".  So when you log in, if that banned user is also logged in, they will not see your "logged-in" event, but all others will. So adding all valid users to a notification group for that event then send to group is what I was thinking.  Group exists until the notification is sent rather than iterating through that list and doing individual private sends.  Recommended method?

Comment: Use Groups. Keep track of membership elsewhere and use groups to select what clients should get what message.